# How to integrate a Backgroundworker with return values

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I want to query datas from a measurement plate. I go through it with 2 for Loops thus x axis and y axis. Unfortunately there is a huge delay if I just use one thread. 
I have no experience with backgroundthreads, I tried a lot but I got many Errors.

I want to query all y axis values with the backgroundworker, but I dont know how to use the backgroundworker that you got values returned . Do you have any idea how i can integrate the backgroundworker ?

Here is my Code clipping:

```
var bufferMatrix = new object();
            var bufferDigital = new object();


            do
            {
                int read = TheDevice.Transfer();
                if ((read & (int)Transfer.TransferDataReady) != 0)
                {
                    if (Matrix != null)
                    {
                        if (Digital != null)
                        {
                            int quantcount = Matrix.GetQuantCount();
                            int quantCountDigi = Digital.GetQuantCount();
                            // Console.WriteLine("{0} quants downloaded from matrix component", Quantcount);
                            if ((quantcount & quantCountDigi) > 0)
                            {
                                Matrix.CreateCompatibleBuffer(ref bufferMatrix);
                                Digital.CreateCompatibleBuffer(ref bufferDigital);

                                Digital.GetQuants(0, quantCountDigi, bufferDigital, 0);
                                byte[] quantDigi = (byte[])bufferDigital;

                                byte[,] quant = new byte[Matrix.GetSizeX(), Matrix.GetSizeY()];
                                Matrix.GetQuant(quantcount - 1, ref bufferMatrix); //Bekommt Quants und schreibt auf buffer
                                quant = (byte[,])bufferMatrix;



                                double force = 0;



                                double res = Matrix.GetRes() * Matrix.GetResX() * Matrix.GetResY() * 0.01;
                                for (int x = 0; x < Matrix.GetSizeX(); x++)  //X-Achse Schleife 
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine();
                                    Console.WriteLine();
                                    Console.WriteLine();


                                    for (int y = 0; y < Matrix.GetSizeY(); y++) //Y-Achse Schleife 
                                    {
                                        // var digi = quantDigi[x, y];                                           
                                        force += quant[x, y];
                                        if (force > 0)
                                        {
                                            quantListY.Add(force);
                                            Console.Write(x+" , "+y+" => "+force*res);

                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                }

            } while (!Console.KeyAvailable || Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.S);
```

Comment: Use tasks, not the background worker

Comment: But how can i use Tasks. Because I cant return multiple values and if I try to use new Task(void Method) it doesnt work.

Comment: You shouldn.t use the task constructor. Use the `Task.Run` and, maybe, some loop inside it.